# Django assignment tag issue

Tags: django

For some reason this is returning nothing for me, no errors but just not getting anything returned by the tag.

taglist.py

```
from django import template
from article.models import Tag

register = template.Library()

@register.assignment_tag
def taglist():
return Tag.objects.values('name').distinct()
```

base.html

```
{% load taglist %}
{% block sidebar %}
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/articles/all">Articles</a></li>
        <li><a href="/admin/">Admin</a></li>
        {% taglist as mytags %}
        {% for t in mytags %}
        <li><a href="/articles/tags/{{t}}/">{{t}}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Any idea whats happening here?  The same Tag.objects.... returns what I want it to when done in the shell.

Comment: Did you already restart your server?

Comment: Can't see what's wrong there, but it looks like that would be better as an inclusion tag: the for loop and its contents would go in the included template.

Comment: `.values()` returns a list of dictionaries. I guess that is the reason you are not seeing any output.

Comment: `{% with taglist as mytags %} ... {% endwith %}` ?

Comment: I also think you want to use `objects.values_list('name', flat=True).distinct()` ...